# How to float text element to right with png element to left in nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a nav bar with a png link to the top left corner, and a text element "menu" to the top right corner. I haven't been able to get this to work with "float: right;"

I've included the code that shows I used float: right; for the .topnav elements. I'm not sure if .logo is interfering with this. I needed the png logo to be aligned with the text element which was not possible without putting them in separate divs.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav_right {
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="####.png" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="topnav_right">
      <a href="index.html">Menu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text still remain next to the logo, when it should be in the opposite corner to the right.

Comment: like this?https://jsfiddle.net/jx7dznwm/

Comment: Yes - what did you change to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `container` class, instead of having `position: absolute` , do `position: flex` . It will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a Navbar with left-aligned png-link and right-aligned text, it can be achieved in a much simpler way using flex-box, with the need of nesting them.
It also handles alignment easily

You can read more about flexbox from [csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
<style>
    .topnav {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
        align-items:center;
    }
</style>
<div class="topnav">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img   src="###.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <a href="index.html">Menu</a>
    </div>
</div>
```